# Spritekit - How to hide iAd banner on specific scenes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a Spritekit project.

I have 3 scenes: MainMenu, Game, Gameover

I would like to have the iAd show only when the user is on the Game scene and the Gameover scene.

This is my current code for iAd in my ViewController.m:

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{

        // For iAds
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
        _bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        _bannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        _bannerView.delegate = self;
        _bannerView.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
}

#pragma mark - iAds delegate methods
    - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
        // Occurs when an ad loads successfully
        _bannerView.hidden = NO;
    }

    - (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
        // Occurs when an ad fails to load
        _bannerView.hidden = YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
        // Occurs when the user taps on ad and opens it


        return YES;
    }

    - (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
        // Occurs when the ad finishes full screen
    }
```

The problem is, since the MainMenu scene is the first scene to display, the banner shows there upon successfully loading an ad. 
How do I make it only appear when the user is on the Game scene and the Gameover scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach here is to use `NSNotificationCenter:`

Register notification in your - `(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"hideAd" object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];
```

And handle the Notification here

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
 { 
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"hideAd"])
        {
             // hide your banner;
    }else if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) 
        {
             // show your banner
    }
 }
```

And in your scense

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil]; //Sends message to viewcontroller to show ad.

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideAd" object:nil]; //Sends message to viewcontroller to hide ad.
```

Thanks and best of luck.